# Can I place SVG elements at a certain distance along a path?

Tags: javascript, svg

Say I have an arbitrary `<path>` element that wraps around in a spiral shape (or any other shape) and does not terminate in a self-connection (it just ends).

I also have a bunch of `<svg>` (or `<g>`) elements, we'll say 20 for the purposes of example, that I'd like to spread out over the length of the path.

For example, the first `<g>` will be at the start of the path, the last `<g>` will be at the end of the path, and the rest will be distributed evenly across the path.

Other than calculating the absolute coordinates of the points I need by somehow obtaining a mathematical formula for the arbitrary path and working backwards, how can I place these elements along the path?

For this I'm using JavaScript with no SVG library.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In theory you can with SVG 2 but there's no native support for that yet. In the meantime you can use [getPointAtLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getPointAtLength) to do it yourself.